# URL from Origin has been blocked by CORS policy when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set

Tags: nginx, cors

I have a site that is requesting static files from a CDN. Many of the files are able to be used on the site, but some are being blocked by a CORS policy.

It's blocking html, json, woff, and woff2 files, but letting all other files by, including js, css, jpg and others.

It's a Magento 2 site using nginx. Here is the nginx.conf file where I have added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

```
location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
}
```

And here is magento2-cors.conf:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' 'always';

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' 'always';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'x-requested-with' 'always';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400 'always';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0 'always';
    return 204;
}
```

What I don't get is why will CORS block some of the files and not others. All files are coming in through the same CDN. They are all coming from the static directory, which is what the above nginx.conf is referencing. js and css are apart of the same block as html and woff, but they aren't being blocked while html and woff are.

I've flushed browser cache and magento cache. I've restarted nginx multiple times, nothing seems to work.

Comment: The js, css, jpg cases succeed because probably they are requests being made with `<script>`, `<link>`, and `<img>` elements in HTML markup — and browsers don’t enforce the same-origin policy for `<script>`, `<link>`, and `<img>` elements in HTML markup. In constrast, the json case fails because probably it’s being made from frontend JavaScript code, and in that case, browsers enforce the same-origin policy. And the woff cases fail because also in that special case, browsers enforce the same-origin policy (unlike the `<script>`, `<link>`, and `<img>` cases).

Comment: You probably want to update the question to show some frontend code that’s not working as expected, along with the exact error messages the browser is logging in the devtools console. Given that the blocking doesn’t happen at the server side (the browser is sending responses for all the requests), what matters is context from which the requests are being made — specifically, whether the requests are being made from frontend JavaScript code vs being initiated from HTML markup.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the include, see if putting

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

without any if statement around it does the trick.

Try it after this line

```
location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
```

You can also try putting the fonts in a subdirectory (ie: fonts) and see if that improves your situation.

If that doesn't work, try putting the * origin header immediately after

```
location /static/ {
```

Best of luck!

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It didn't work.